# Master Master Replication Issue

Tags: mysql, database-replication, mysql-5.5

I have found two common issues in master2 replication

1. Handling auto increment:

-- Master1 -- 
auto_increment_increment = 2
auto_increment_offset = 1

-- Master2 -- 
auto_increment_increment = 2
auto_increment_offset = 2

These settings should result in an arithmetic progression for the auto-increment columns:
- Master1: 1,3,5,7,9,11,13  ...
- Master2: 2,4,6,8,10,12,14 ...

2. Handling unique key : 
   Assume i have two masters.
   What if two user try to register with same email-id at same time and both goes to different server and therefor email-id get inserted.

How to handle such cases.

Also is there any list of such issues in master2 replication

Answer (score 1):

Your point1 handling auto_increment is not an issue as it is handled by master-master replication-

But point2 is a concern as you have to manage your transactions in your application carefully otherwise replication will collapse.

You can check details at below links-

[link1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-master_replication)

[link2](http://scale-out-blog.blogspot.in/2012/04/if-you-must-deploy-multi-master.html)